# If and else code blocks running together

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I am trying to cycle through a form on load (that may have fields pre-populated) and assign a check or a cross if the field is filled in or blank respectively.

The jQuery is:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    
      // test code for dynamic validation
      var $feedback = '.form-feedback';
      var $icon = 'i';
      var $good = 'ion-checkmark-circled';
      var $bad = 'ion-close-circled';
    
      // form selectors
      var arr = ["username", "first-name", "last-name"];
    
      $.each(arr, function(i, val) {
        if ($("#form-" + val ).val() !== '') {
          console.log("#form-" + val + ": "+ $good);
          $("#form-" + val ).siblings($feedback).find($icon).addClass($good);
        } else {
          console.log("#form-" + val+ ": "+ $bad);
          $('.main-input-field input').siblings($feedback).find($icon).addClass($bad);
        }
      });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Username:</p>
    <p class="main-input-field"><input id="form-username" class="username" type="text" name="UserName" ><span class="form-feedback"><i></i></span></p>
    <p>First Name:</p>
    <p class="main-input-field"><input type="text" id="form-first-name" name="FirstName" ><span class="form-feedback"><i></i></span></p>
    <p>Surname:</p>
    <p class="main-input-field"><input type="text" id="form-last-name" name="Surname" ><span class="form-feedback"><i></i></span></p>
```

As you can see I have a blank `<i>` element which I want to add a class which will display either a check or a cross. When the input field is blank it works great, but if the input field has a value, it runs the code then also adds the else code (i.e. adds the $good class then adds the $bad class as well). The result is a cross on all outcomes.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: I think your code has some errors, if possible please remove the PHP code, so will be easier to examine your code

Comment: @andrepaulo done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not because else runs as well. It is because you are using siblings().

try to run this:

```
console.log($('.main-input-field input').siblings('.form-feedback'));
```

you will change them all. Read [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) on how siblings works

Comment: ah I see. I am using the general class selector instead of the id of that element. Thanks.